# Completely Uninstall IntelliJ on Debian

Tags: debian, intellij

Can someone please tell me how I can completely uninstall IntelliJ from Debian? I followed [this article](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519) but did not see anything under `~/.` for IntelliJ (for superuser or regular user)

I want to reinstall and get the installation wizard, but I am not able to. When I delete the installation directory and try and reinstall, it just runs and doesn't show me the installation wizard, so something is lingering on somewhere!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @StephenKitt maybe "install wizard" is the wrong term, but there definitely was a wizard, and I exited it too soon, but among other things, it allowed for creation of desktop icons

Comment: Yep, here is a [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/915oL).

Comment: You need to run `ls -a`, `ls` won’t show directories starting with `.`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that! I'm a linux n00b

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To completely remove the preferences stored by IntelliJ, and thus see its setup wizard the next time you run it, remove the hidden directories it uses from your home directory:

```
rm -rf ~/.IdeaIC* ~/.IntelliJIdea* ~/.ideaLibSources
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked, and I got the wizard again! much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The folders starting with a '.' are hidden folders in Linux, meaning you need to add the flag -a (all) to ls to view them. Try this:

```
ls -la ~/
```

And you should find the folders starting with a dot created by IntelliJ on your home folder.

Also, if you installed it with a .deb or from a repo use the "purgue" option or apt to automatically remove the configuration files, which is what is being stored in that folder:

```
sudo apt purge intelliJ
```

You'll have to check the name of the package though, I don't know if it's called like that.